# how to split a word into two words by adding a space between adjacent characters

Tags: java, spell-checking, trie

I am trying to take the word: *missspelling* and split the word into two words by adding a " " (space) between adjacent chars and want to get the word: *miss spelling* as a result. Any guidance would help, been trying out different code, but have not seen results.

Code that works for other suggestions for reference only. *Note that commented out code is what I have been messing with to try and get the correct result.

```
    /**
     * Returns possible suggestions for misspelled word
     * 
     * @param tree The Trie that will be checked
     * @param word The word in trie that is checked
     */
    public static void suggest(TrieNode tree, String word) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        System.out.println("Suggestions: ");
        // Remove a character
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
            result.add(word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1));
        // Swap two consecutive characters
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; ++i)
            result.add(word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1, i + 2) + word.substring(i, i + 1)
                    + word.substring(i + 2));
        // Replace a character with other
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
                result.add(word.substring(0, i) + String.valueOf(c) + word.substring(i + 1));
        // Add a new character
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); ++i)
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
                result.add(word.substring(0, i) + String.valueOf(c) + word.substring(i));
        // Split word into pair of words by adding a " " between adjacent pairs
        // Need help here
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
            for (char c = ' '; c <= ' '; ++c)
                if (search(tree, word.substring(0, i)) && search(tree, word.substring(i)) == true)
                     result.add(word.substring(0, i) + String.valueOf(c) + word.substring(i));


        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>(result);
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
            if (search(tree, res.get(i))) {
                if (j == 0)
                    System.out.print("[");
                System.out.print(res.get(i) + ",");
                System.out.print("");
                j++;
            }
         System.out.print("]" + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: I have seen your previous question on the site today, which is exactly the same as this one. While this one is worded better, you should wait at least 48 hours before reposting.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, Okay

Comment: @BenjaminLowry I don't think you should repost anyway, that's what bounties are for imo. If you can word it better you should edit the original.

Comment: Ok, how do you determine that you want to break the word "missspelling" into miss spelling, and not mi ssspelling or misssp elling?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I want to break the word by adding a space between adjacent characters and then having an if statement that checks the dictionary to see if each of the split words are both in a dictionary.  I have replaced the jumble of commeted out code with code that should work, but does not print out (something is missing maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a minimal, runnable piece of code that splits words if the two word pieces are found in the dictionary.

Here are my test results

```
miss spelling
apple
```

And here's the code.  The important method is the splitWord method.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DoubleWord implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoubleWord().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
        System.out.println(splitWord("missspelling", dictionary));
        System.out.println(splitWord("apple", dictionary));
    }

    public String splitWord(String word, Dictionary dictionary) {
        for (int index = 1; index < word.length(); index++) {
            String prefix = word.substring(0, index);
            if (dictionary.isWordInDictionary(prefix)) {
                String suffix = word.substring(index);
                if (dictionary.isWordInDictionary(suffix)) {
                    return prefix + " " + suffix;
                }
            }
        }

        return word;
    }

    public class Dictionary {
        private List<String> words;

        public Dictionary() {
            this.words = setWords();
        }

        public boolean isWordInDictionary(String word) {
            return words.contains(word);
        }

        private List<String> setWords() {
            List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
            words.add("apple");
            words.add("miss");
            words.add("spelling");
            words.add("zebra");

            return words;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This code does what I ask for, and I will mark it as the answer. I still have yet to figure out why my code is not adding the suggested word to the output list of suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things first...

This line is insane:

```
for (char c = ' '; c <= ' '; ++c)
```

It will iterate exactly once and is equivalent to:

```
char c = ' ';
```

---

You are reinventing the wheel by attempting to find valid words by swapping chars and then by substituting chars: Read about [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), implement that algorithm, then sort your dictionary by the Levenshtein distance from your input to find "best matches", which should be filtered by a maximum Levenshtein distance - perhaps 3 would be a good starting point (test your code and see if the result is reasonable).

---

Your `TrieNode` should have a `search()` method, rather than your `search()` method accepting a trie and a word, but that's more a matter of design and isn't your biggest problem.

---

Now then, regarding your actual question, attempting to split the input is complicated, but the "answer" is:

*Loop through all positions in the input between letters, and put each "half" through the same process as your input, except that you should not do a nested split, combining every combination of suggestions for each half, then return a collection of all unique suggestion combniations*.

However, doing this this will result is a "very large" number of suggestions and thus will not scale, so you probably shouldn't do it.